# Filter transactions by time on a given address

Tags: transactions, query

Is there an API that will list all transactions made on a given wallet address with the ability to filter by date? I prefer nodejs, but open to other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you were looking for but there's a site that does exactly this, check it out.

https://goochain.net/

Filter on dates/ find adresses with partial numbers etc.

Comment: I dont see any APIs I can call programmatically

Answer (score 0):

On Blockchair you can do that, e.g. to find all transactions to Satoshis Genesis block address 1A1zP1eP5QGefi2DMPTfTL5SLmv7DivfNa made in 2023 you could go to: https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/outputs?s=time(asc)&q=recipient(1A1zP1eP5QGefi2DMPTfTL5SLmv7DivfNa),time(2023-01-01..2023-12-31)

To build that URL you need to go under "outputs explorer", then filter by "Recipient" and "Time".