# Fnd the most valuable transactions made to a given address

Tags: blockchain-explorer

E.g. I wanted to see the largest transactions ever made to Satoshi's Genesis block address: 1A1zP1eP5QGefi2DMPTfTL5SLmv7DivfNa

I tried looked on Blockchair under addresses and transactions but couldn't find a way.

Related to filter by time: [Filter transactions by time on a given address](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/71019/filter-transactions-by-time-on-a-given-address)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I had to search under outputs: https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/outputs?s=value(desc)&q=recipient(1A1zP1eP5QGefi2DMPTfTL5SLmv7DivfNa) which makes sense as transactions can have multiple recipients. Then you filter by "Recipient" and sort by "Value".